# GRASS_Addones dialog box not showing

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, add-ons

I am using Grass 7.2.1 as a package in QGIS(2.18.13). I want to use the r.skyview addons. I installed the library and tried to run it from Python in GRASS. When I run the code in the python shell, the dialog box (where I have to identify the input, output files and the parameters)  is not showing. as a result it gives error of missing input data. How to fix this.